# Puppeteer missing when running script with cronjob

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am having a strange issue when attempting to run puppeteer with a cron job. Code as follows:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const stealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')();

stealthPlugin.enabledEvasions.delete('user-agent-override');
puppeteer.use(stealthPlugin);

const userAgent = UserAgentOverride({
    userAgent: 'some agent,
    locale: 'en-US,en'
});
puppeteer.use(userAgent);

const options = {
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [
        '--disable-sync',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors'
    ],
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']
};

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
```

When I run the code in the terminal there are no issue however the code fails if run from a cron job. I printed the output of the cron job:

```
Puppeteer is missing. :-)

Note: puppeteer is a peer dependency of puppeteer-extra,
which means you can install your own preferred version.

- To get the latest stable version run: 'yarn add puppeteer' or 'npm i puppeteer'

Alternatively:
- To get puppeteer without the bundled Chromium browser install 'puppeteer-core'
- To use puppeteer-firefox install 'puppeteer-firefox' and use the 'addExtra' export
```

I've got no idea why it say it is missing if it works fine in the terminal. Looking at my `package.json` I have:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "puppeteer": "^5.3.1",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.1.15",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.6.1"
  }
```

I tried not using `puppeteer-extra` and just regular `puppeteer` but I get this error:

```
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at promisify (internal/util.js:209:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kekearif/my-project/node_modules/extract-zip/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kekearif/my-project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js:48:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kekearif/my-project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Launcher.js:43:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Hi Kex I encountered the same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: I did. Make sure you include the path to node in the crontab eg `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/kekearif/bot/scripts/bot.js`